# How to sort one array the same as another one?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

My problem:
I have an array of objects which I sort ASC DESC by one of the objects keys, after that I need to sort an array of string that will be sorted the way the object array has been sort.
example:

```
arrayOfObjects = [{name:"john",nuber:6,food:"pizza"},
               {name:"david",nuber:2,food:"gulash"},
               {name:"margaret",nuber:7,food:"gugi barries"}]

arrayOfStrings = ['r1','r2','r3']
```

so each object in arrayOfObjects has its own string. so say, john has r1, and they are both first indexed, when I sort by number john goes second, and I want hes number to go second as well (as well as david and margaret numbers)

I need to re-arrange the arrayOfStrings the same way (I dont care what it was sorted by) the arrayOfObjects was sorted

My sorting function :

```
dataArray.sort(dynamicSort(sortBy)); 
function dynamicSort(property) {
    var sortOrder = 1;
    if(property[0] === "-") {
        sortOrder = -1;
        property = property.substr(1);
    }
    return function (a,b) {
        if(direction=='asc'){
            var c = b;
            b=a;
            a=c;
        }
        var result = ( b[property] < a[property]) ? -1 : ( b[property]> a[property]) ? 1 : 0;
        return result * sortOrder;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could add a property to your objects that will be sorted, like `{name:"john", r:'r1' ...` and then retrieve these values when the array is sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you zip the list in the format `[[object, string], ...]` and then sort according to the first element of the tuple. You can unzip the list afterwards.

Comment: That is a good idea, I had a similar one, just to add each string to its original object, at the key:string and to read it from there. 
though I wanted to see if there is a way I can 'remember what the the sort changed'

Comment: @nadiTime No, I'm pretty sure there isn't, it's not practical at all. I mean at best you'd be doing the sorting work *twice* which is not something that you want. Just do it all in one go -- either way will do (your or mine), it's just a matter of whether it makes sense for the string to be a part of the object or not.

Comment: your absolutely right, I don't want to sort the array again. thanks

Comment: @nadiTime If that's it then, you can accept the answer :)